# XCode git creating "[7;33mmaster[m" instead of master branch

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5, git-branch

When i create a new project or open an existing project in XCode i get this strange branch name:
[image: master branch after creating project]

When i try to create a development branch i get this:
[image: Creating a new branch]

If i go to Source Control > Working Copies > Configure i get this:
[image]

However if i open the project in the console the branch name is ok:
[image]

Same in SourceTree:
[image]

Problem:

- Can't push to remote repos through XCode because of the distorted branch name.

Tried:

- Reinstalling XCode. (moving it to the trash and installing it again from the Appstore)
- Reinstalling Command line tools.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: you need to fix your branches names. can you post the result of `git branch` ?

Comment: As you can read at the top it happens to all my projects, it seems a configuration issue.

Comment: [7,33m apparently means 'invert yellow', which is consistent with the branch name displayed in your shell. Don't know where that could come from, though (not to mention that the ps1 does not seem affected)

Comment: which leads me to think there is something messed up in the name of your branch.

Comment: is there a way to reset everything? I've installed this https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles for the console colors.

Comment: you can start by trying if `git branch -m master master` does anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The dotfiles messed up my xcode, all i needed to do is to uninstall the configuration:

```
unlink ~/.bin
unlink ~/.gitignore
unlink ~/.gemrc
unlink ~/.gvimrc
unlink ~/.irbrc
unlink ~/.vim
unlink ~/.vimrc
rm ~/.zshrc # careful here
rm ~/.gitconfig
rm -rf ~/.dotfiles
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

Source: https://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles#uninstall

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in atom and sublime text. My culprit was in my .gitconfig file.

Changing the option:

```
[color]
    ui = always
```

to:

```
[color]
    ui = auto
```

solved it for me.